# Can you call a member of member of template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I seem to be doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what. Here's the smallest example of what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

class CallMe {
 public:
  void Maybe() {
    cout << "A";
  }
};

class TemplateValue {
 public:
  static CallMe call_me;
};

template<typename T>
void CallMemberMember() {
  T::call_me.Maybe();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  CallMemberMember<TemplateValue>();
}
```

When I try to build this, I get a link error:

```
$ clang++ --std=c++11 repro_link_error.cc
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "TemplateValue::call_me", referenced from:
      void CallMemberMember<TemplateValue>() in repro_link_error-9BE9gw.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The rule of thumb is: If it's a linker error, yes you can.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to provide definition for static member `call_me`:

```
CallMe TemplateValue::call_me;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  CallMemberMember<TemplateValue>();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with templates: You need to provide the *definition* for the static class member:

```
class TemplateValue {
 public:
  static CallMe call_me;
};

CallMe TemplateValue::call_me;
```

(You should learn to distinguish compiler errors from linker errors. Your code was compiling fine, it was just not complete.)

Comment: First of all, don't be so pedantic. Second, I said I was having a link error; I never said I was having a compiler error. Third, I copy n' pasted exactly the output I was seeing, which should be enough to understand understand my question.

Comment: @allyourcode: I wasn't being pedantic, I just wanted to offer a suggestion to help you narrow down the problem. If you know that something compiles, but doesn't link, you can rule out a lot of concerns. For example, if you pursue the linker error, you could narrow the question down to one which never mentions the word "template" :-)

Answer (score 0):

You declared `call_me` as static. Static objects require definition just like methods and functions. You need to initialize it like this:

```
CallMe TemplateValue::call_me = CallMe();
```